# Array manipulation in systemverilog

Tags: filter, verilog, signal-processing, system-verilog

```
logic [M-1:0] x [N-1:0]; // x is N number of rows and M number of bits
genvar i;
genvar j;

for (i=0; i<N; i++) begin
     for (j=0; j<M; j++) begin
         x[i][j] = $random;
     end
end
```

In the real code, it is not random, but this is an input bit. But the same error is introduced which is

```
token is '['
x[i][j]
```

making a pointer on the second [

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `generate` construct, you can not have a bare assignment statement there.  Use the `assign` keyword:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) begin
     for (j=0; j<M; j++) begin
         assign x[i][j] = $random;
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that you use a `generate` construct to initialize an array in a purely behavioral way. The construct is used to simply replicate verilog statements, such as *assign* or module instances.

Usually such initialization is done in `initial` blocks, like the following:

```
initial begin
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) begin
     for (int j=0; j<M; j++) begin
         x[i][j] = $random;
     end
  end
end
```